# Angular 6 - Mat-Dialog slow opening with Chrome

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm using Mat-Dialog component from Angular Material (6.0.1 release).

When opening a dialog with Chrome browser, the opening animation is quite slow.

When I use Firefox, Safari, MS Edge then the opening animation is fine.

I've recorded the performance profile which seems to indicate slowness occurs when animation is played while the dialog is being open:

[image]

I could see another topic on Stackoverflow with somehow a similar issue: [Why is Angular 5 with Angular Material Dialog slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953801/why-is-angular-5-with-angular-material-dialog-slow)

Is there any way to address it other than disabling animation ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you upgrade all @angular dependencies to 6.0.1?

Comment: I made a Stackblitz using Angular 6.0.1 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-fast-dialog, and it does appear a bit laggy on chrome, but I just wanted to ask if you find the animation faster or slower than your application's dialog?

Comment: @John yes all upgraded to 6.0.1

Comment: Your Stackblitz exactly reproduces the same laggy behaviour as my app. On my app, the lag is even more apparent with Chrome as the dialog is displayed with 1400px width / 900px height.

Comment: I know that removing the css: `box-shadow` from the dialog makes it less slow, but it is not a good solution.

Comment: FYI, issue open on Github https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11330